# What is the control flow and recursion tree in python

Tags: recursion, control-flow

I have a simple doubt:

I have found the power of number code using recursion as:

```
def power(x, y): 

    if(y == 0): return 1
    temp = power(x, int(y / 2))  
    print("outside loop:",temp)

    if (y % 2 == 0): 
        print("inner loop y%2==0:",temp*temp)
        return temp * temp 
    else: 
        if(y > 0): 
            print(" loop y > 0:",x*temp*temp)
            return x * temp * temp 
        else: return (temp * temp) / x 
power(2,3)
```

What would be the control flow and recursive diagram of the above code?
Is `temp=power(x, int(y / 2))` called 3 times first and then the control reaches to `else:  if(y > 0):`?

Any help would be great. Simple printing will not help.

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: The print statements should be able to answer that. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Simple printing doesn't help. Can you help me with recursion tree?